# Popup Window and ElementName in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have ListBox with ItemTemplate that contain a ToggleButton:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lbInvoice" ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsinInvoice}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="btnInvoiceItem">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="375">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}" Width="200"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalePrice}" Width="60"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" Width="40"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Also, I have Popup window ,I want this Popup window opend when I check the ToggleButton, Here's my Popup code:

```
        <Popup x:Name="popup" PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnInvoiceItem}" StaysOpen="False">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="pla pla pla"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
```

I set the btnInvoiceItem as ElementName for Popup but the Popup window dose not appear beside the ToggleButton :(

what I miss here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`btnInvoiceItem` only exists within the context of the `ListBoxItem` that corresponds to the item in your collection. Therefore, the simplest way to do what you want is to put the Popup in the same DataTemplate as the button.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnInvoiceItem">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="375">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}" Width="200"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SalePrice}" Width="60"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" Width="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Total}" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Width="70"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Popup PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btnInvoiceItem, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="pla pla pla"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to do something like this:

```
<Popup IsOpen={Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnInvoiceItem} x:Name="popup" PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnInvoiceItem}" StaysOpen="False">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="pla pla pla"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
```

Comment: This won't work outside of the DataTemplate. If this Popup is defined anywhere outside the DataTemplate, then `btnInvoiceItem` cannot be resolved.

Comment: yes this is correct it would have to reside inside of the DataTemplate in order resolve properly.